# In swift, Is it necessary to set the strong variables to nil after its use?

Tags: ios, swift

I basically use outlets as weak variables, like

```
@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!
```

But what will happen if i use strong instead of weak, like

```
@IBOutlet var testButton: UIButton!
```

Do I have to set it to nil after its use?

Comment: Actually strong Outlets will remains in the memory . Outlets are not optionals so you cannot assign them nil otherwise you got crash.

Comment: Strong will be there until any of your own created object holds it. So, to answer your question "Is it necessary to set the strong variables to nil after its use?" --> No.

Comment: http://scottberrevoets.com/2016/03/21/outlets-strong-or-weak/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlets as weak are fine as long as they are on screen as subviews. in fact they will be retained by the `subviews` array of their superView. As soon as they will get removed from the screen (therefore from the `subviews` array) the `retainCount` will decrease of one. If the only strong reference of the outlet is in the `subviews` array (weak property case) then the `retainCount` will be zero, the object will be deallocated and your `testButton` property will become nil. In this case, you will never be able to reuse your `testButton` property, as it is force unwrapped and any access would cause a crash. If the view can be removed from the screen programmatically it might be a good idea to set this property as `?` optional.

You want this property to get a strong reference to the outlet if you want programmatically remove this outlet from the screen, and successively re add it as subview programmatically based on some user interaction logic. In this case, having a strong reference the removeFromSuperView method will decrease the retain count that will still be 1, as your property is retaining the object.

if you set to nil your strong reference, and the object is no longer a subview, then it will be deallocated, and you will not be able to reuse your testButton property.

If you set to nil your strong reference, but the object is still a subview in your view hierarchy, then it will remain there until its superview is destroyed, but you will never be able to manipulate that object again, as your reference to the object is gone.

In general if in your program logic a property can become nil during its scope it's safer to declare it as `?` optional and not as `!` force unwrapped optional because the force unwrapped will cause crashes if accessed while they are nil.

I hope I was clear enough and that I answered to your doubts.

**Edit:**

Creating the view programmatically; First it's a good idea to not have an outlet for reference. if a new developer steps into your project and see an outlet he expects to find it on a xib or a storyboard the corresponding outlet; he will not expect to see this outlet created via code.

Anyway here we must pay attention to some cases. But all of them fallbacks on the same rule:

- weak does not increase retain counts, strong does.
- An object that has retain count == 0 is immediately deallocated.
- A weak reference pointing to a deallocated instance immediately changes to nil

To understand better:

```
weak var testButton: UIButton!

func createButton() {
    testButton = UIButton()
    //Here testButton is already nil, because testButton is weak and
    //the new UIButton is not retained.
    view.addSubiew(testButton) //crash, because you are accessing 
    //a nil force unwrapped property
}
```

defining tesButton as strong here fixes the issue.

Different is the following case:

```
weak var testButton: UIButton!

func createButton() {
    let localTestButton = UIButton() //this is strong
    testButton = localTestButton //this is weak
    //here the new UIButton is retained by the localTestButton var
    //so its retainCount is 1, so testButton is not nil as its 
    //reference is not deallocated
    view.addSubview(testButton) //all good, this retains the UIButton
    //that now has a retain count of 2
    //At the end of the scope, all the local var are released, and
    //their pointed objects decreases the retainCount.
    //in this scope there is just the localTestButton that is released
    //so the pointed object's retain count decreases from 2 to 1.
    //if in another scope the subview is removed (testButton.removeFromSuperView())
    //then the UIButton retain count is 0 and it is deallocated.
    //testButton will immediately become nil and no longer usable.
}
```

Comment: @ARUN KUMAR I answered you editing the post. Hope all is clear now.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting some bad answers.

Outlets are usually weak, **and** implicitly unwrapped optionals. That's what the `!` after the type indicates.

Outlets are declared as weak in order to avoid keeping the view hierarchy in memory after it's no longer needed. (Normally the outlet is owned by it's superview, and simply removing it from it's superview causes it to get deallocated. Usually that's the correct behavior. If you want an outlet to persist after it's removed from it's superview you can either create another strong reference or make the outlet strong, but in that case it's up to you to nil it out when you're done with it)

Outlets **should** be declared as weak, with very few exceptions. Yes, if you declare them as strong then you should nil them when you are done with them. (Although if your view controller is deallocated then it doesn't matter since its strong references will go away.)

Comment: What is in the case of normal variables like  'var tableData = NSArray()' .

Comment: "Outlets are declared as weak in order to avoid retain cycles". I think that's not the reason: views should not have strong references to the controller layer. I assume `IBOutlet`s are created weak to make view unloading work. I always make them `strong` as view unloading is a thing of the past.

Comment: I would argue that there is no reason to make outlets weak considering that in 99% cases they should be kept in memory exactly the same time as their owner. What really strikes me as wrong is the combination of `weak` and implicitly unwrapped optional. If you want something to be weak, it means it's nillable, therefore a normal optional should be used.

Comment: I think the idea is that outlets should be connected and valid by the time you reference them, and you WANT to crash if an outlet is nil.

Comment: In addition to avoiding circular references, good memory hygiene also says that one object shouldn't have multiple strong references to another. By convention, views are owned by their superview. The view controller owns the content view, and the content view owns it's subviews, etc. If outlets were strong, then the view controller would have 2 separate ownership "object graphs" to the view: Through the view hierarchy and from the outlet.

Comment: Its not that unusual to have a view controller swap out some subviews for other subviews. In that case, if your outlets are weak, simply removing a subview from it's superview and replacing it with a different subview causes the old subview to be released, and that's the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

In ARC a property is strong by default.
Each UI element will be released when controller is released so dont worry about releasing Storyboad UI Elements or setting them nil(crash might happen).

Comment: each ui element created within IB is weak and that let your viewController release.